# Eclipse RCP: Does CNF without IDE plug-in require custom ContentProvider?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, cnf

In an RCP application, I'd like to create a Common Navigator Framework view, starting just with resources on the local file system.

I've done that in one project that includes the *org.eclipse.ui.ide* plug-in. However, that creates a UI that is over-complex and inappropriate for this application. (For example, it adds about 20 preferences panels, some associated with builds and version control.)

So now I'm trying to do it without the ~.ide plug-in -- and without the *org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources* plug-in which depends on it.

In the RCP app, I've managed to create a new workspace project (I think) with the code below, in a plugin with the ~navigator.viewer extensions shown below. But nothing appears in the CNF view.

**Questions:**

- Since I am excluding the *org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources* plug-in, do I need to define my own content provider?
- Is the class ResourceExtensionContentProvider in the *org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources* plug-in used to implement the content binding *org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent*?

**plugin.xml excerpt**

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
   <viewerActionBinding
        viewerId="com.mycompany.app.gen.workspace">
     <includes>
         <actionExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.*" />
     </includes>
   </viewerActionBinding>
   <viewerContentBinding 
        viewerId="com.dnastar.app.gen.workspace">
      <includes>
         <contentExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent" />                      
     <contentExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.*"/>
         <contentExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.linkHelper"/>
         <contentExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.workingSets"/>
      </includes>
   </viewerContentBinding>
 </extension>
```

**Code used to create a new project (included for completeness):**

```
        Path path = new Path( sPath );
        File filePath = new File( sPath );
        String fileBaseName = filePath.getName();
        String projectName = fileBaseName; // For now

        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
        IProjectDescription projDescr = workspace.newProjectDescription( projectName );
        projDescr.setLocation( path );

        IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
        IProject project = root.getProject( projectName );

        try {
            project.create( projDescr, null );

            if ( ! project.isOpen() ) {
                project.open( null );
            }
        } catch (CoreException e) {
             MessageDialog.openError( Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(),
                     "New Project Error", "Could not create new project." + "\n[" + e + "]");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the CommonNavigator class, you need to extend it and then override the getInitialInput() method. There return IWorkspaceRoot

Comment: Still not getting anything displayed in the navigator window. Subclassed CommonNavigator, and in getInitialInput() returned ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(). In plugin.xml, replaced the class of the CommonNavigator view with the subclass. Thanks for helping. Am I missing anything?

Comment: No. That should work. Do you have any projects in the workspace? If so I suggest you to raise a bug in the Eclipse Bugzilla.

Comment: Would I need to provide a custom label provider somewhere?

Comment: In a project *with* the plug-ins ~ide and ~navigator.resources, the content is being obtained with the ~navigator.resources class ResourceExtensionContentProvider.